# How to read and write simultaneously from same file in C#

Tags: c#, file, filestream, streamwriter, operation

i want to write the data in file and also read it to display simultaneously from the same in C#.
how to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

and then you can call

```
 long oldPos = fs.Position;
 fs.Write(....);
 fs.Flush();
 fs.Position = oldPos;
 fs.Read(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Flush after writing and read it afterwards.

By the way, why don't display it from memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can open a FileStream for both reading and writing. For example:

```
byte[] writeBuffer; // Contains data to write
byte[] readBuffer;  // Large enough space to read data
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("file.txt", 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadAndWrite);
fileStream.Write(writeBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length);
fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
```

You can use the same object to do reads and writes. However, doing both simultaneously requires careful coordination in your application to prevent the operations interfering with each other. A better solution might be to queue the operations.